# How to create a link which will execute js code in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I was wondering how to create a link in a view (index.html.erb) which will execute js/jquery code.

I am using https://github.com/akzhan/jwysiwyg and is looking to hide the editor but not sure how to do it.

Right now I am doing

EDIT -

index.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "Hide", "#", onclick: "$('#email_body').hide();" %>
```

index.js.erb

```
$('#wysiwyg').wysiwyg('clear');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use rails link_to helper for this:

```
link_to "Hide", "#", confirm: "Are you sure?", onclick: "$('#wysiwyg').wysiwyg('clear');"
```

Better coding practice would be to separate the JavaScript code from your view code, for example:

```
link_to "Hide", "#", id: 'hide_editor'
```

then, in a separate JavaScript file:

```
(function(){
  $('#hide_editor').on('click', function(){
    $('#wysiwyg').wysiwyg('clear');
  });
})();
```

Then place a link to this JS before your closing BODY tag.

UPDATE:
As I can see, this plugin doesn't support disabling, you can disable it by hiding the container: `$('#wysiwyg').hide();`

`$('#wysiwyg').wysiwyg('clear')` clears the contents of the editor, as I see it in the docs.

UPDATE2: 
  @iCyborg, based on your code, here is the working example: http://jsbin.com/esuyij/1/

UPDATE3: I've looked into this editor and find its customization options not flexible enough. May I suggest you look into other editors? For example there is a line-up here:
http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/html5-wysiwyg/

Comment: Thanks, I am trying the code given by you, btw that link_to  code is not working, I checked https://github.com/akzhan/jwysiwyg#id10 and it still looks like $('#wysiwyg').wysiwyg('clear'); is used to clear the controls or is it ? I am trying to disable/enable the wysiwyg editor

Comment: Thanks Valentin, I am using <%= link_to "Hide", "#", onclick: "$('#wysiwyg').hide();" %> but it is not hiding the editor, any idea ?

Comment: Google Chrome dev tools is your friend: open up console and type in:
$('#wysiwyg').hide();
If it doesn't work, type: $('#wysiwyg')
If it returns an empty array, jQuery can't find this element. If it returns this element, then wysiwyg plugin is preventing jquery from hiding the activated container.

Comment: you are right, $('#wysiwyg') is giving [], anyway I tested with parent div $('#text_area_body') which is returning the content, but when I am putting <%= link_to "Hide", "#", onclick: "$('#text_area_body').hide();" %> in index.html, it is still not hiding that div, any idea ?

Comment: Velentin, I have added an image to show the html code generated by rails. I tried . too since wysiwyg a class still not working.

Comment: @iCyborg I'v updated my answer with a working example. Please let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks Valentin, I have put the code, now the editor is hidden by default (actually the whole text area) but unfortunately when I again click on the link, the text area doesn't get shown, any idea >

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27319/discussion-between-valentin-vasilyev-and-icyborg)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('#wysiwyg').wysiwyg('clear');" id="NOT_SURE_WHAT_ID_TO_GIVE">Hide Editor Controls</a>
```